# While debugging, how to avoid stepping into code located in different file in asp classic and VBScript?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

When debugging **asp.net** code in visual studio, the flow doesn't go to dependancy files unless you put a break point in the code being called. This is the first time I debug **asp/VBScript** code. It looks to me like I've to go through all the depencies

```
<!--#include virtual="path"-->
```

It's kind of annoying and makes me lose focus of the big picture.

Is there anyway I can skip those files and keep the flow only on the current asp page?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is that in classic ASP, an include file isn't a "dependency" in the traditional sense of the word.  With classic ASP, all of these includes are compiled into the current "page" being requested, creating a single resource.  Much as you cannot conditionally add these files in an If/Then statement, you cannot conditionally remove them.

My suggestion would be to jump between breakpoints and examine variables rather than stepping over each line.

Comment: Yep, that's the only thing to do. Feel much better. Thanks!